# Address translation of a instruction of multiple bytes

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, paging, low-level

Hi my question is simple :
If you have a 4 byte instruction and your operating system makes use of paging. Is it possible that multiple address translations are made to fetch this 4 byte instruction?

I searched de ostep course book but could not find clarification.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditional ISAs with *fixed-width* 4-byte instructions, such as MIPS, require them to be naturally aligned (aligned by 4, low 2 address bits = 0), so they can't span across any larger power-of-2 alignment boundary such as a page.

But there are plenty of ISAs with variable-length instructions where one instruction can span a page boundary, so with virtual memory two different virt->phys translations are needed.  (Typically CPUs fetch blocks like 16 bytes into a buffer or queue and decode out of that, but yes you'd still have two address translations as part of fetching the bytes of one instruction.  Having a fetch buffer is what makes this a non-problem for the most part.)

- x86 and other CISCs like m68k - machine code is an unaligned byte-stream.  For x86, instruction lengths from 1 to 15 bytes are allowed.
- ARM [Thumb 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210531-00/?p=105265), RISC-V [rv32c / rv64c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603355/does-risc-v-compressed-instructions-subset-rvc-always-assemble-into-32-bit-ins), and similar for other RISCs that support compressed instructions (like MicroMIPS) to save i-cache footprint and fetch bandwidth: instructions are 2 or 4 bytes, aligned by 2.
- [ForwardCom](https://www.forwardcom.info/) (exists on paper only) - instructions are one, two, or three 32-bit words. (https://www.forwardcom.info/risc_cisc.php)

See *[Do x86 instructions require their own encoding as well as all of their arguments to be present in memory at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968748/do-x86-instructions-require-their-own-encoding-as-well-as-all-of-their-arguments)* which discusses the worst-case number of pages present at once for forward progress to be possible, including an instruction spanning a page boundary.

---

You might also consider cases like a `MIPS lw $t0, 0($t1)` which page-faults, then after the OS's page-fault handler repairs the situation and returns to user-space, the instruction is re-fetched, needing another address translation.

So that counts as 2 fetches. If lots of tasks are running (and the OS context-switches to something else during the page fault), the code or data might even get evicted again before this task runs again and returns to user-space for code-fetch or the data load to fault again. So the number of address-translations is theoretically unbounded for one *successful* execution.

But still only 1 translation per fetch. (Or 2 for an instruction split across pages.)

Comment: thank you very much I think this is a very useful (for both myself and others) and complete answer, thx for the reformatting